# How to save data from Performance (perfmon)

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, perfmon, jmeter-plugins

I have to run longevity tests in JMeter.

I need to collect performance counters data into file, and then build graphs in Excel with all the supporting information like scales and axis titles.

**Firstly,**
I've tried [PerfMon plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PerfMon) in JMeter, but it didn't work with my server and JMeter reported the error that the Perfmon plugin `is not supported by the SIGAR API on this Operating System`.
Why have I this error?
How can I solve this problem to be able to collect pefrormance data from server and drow beautiful graphs?

**Secondly,** 
now I use Performance aplication on my server (using command `perfmon`).
Server's OS is WindowsXP Professional SP3 x86.
I need to write the data from counters in the log file. But I didn't found how to start and end saving the data in the log file when my tests run.

Could you, please, explain me, how can I

1. save the data during test process in a file?
2. and then build graphs in Excel using this data?